# check if innerhtml changed

Tags: javascript, html, date, datetime, time

I am writing an time clock program for myself and want to check if I have clocked in or not. I want to see if the original html has changed as I think this is better than using a global boolean variable.

My HTML code:

```
<h1 id="startTime">Start Time: </h1>
<h1 id="endTime">End Time: </h1>
<h1 id="totalHours">Total Hours: </h1>
<br>
<button class="button button1" onclick="hoursCalc()">clock in</button>
```

My JS code:

```
function hoursCalc() {
    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();
    if (document.getelementByID === "Start Time: ")
        document.getElementById("startTime").innerHTML += h;
    else 
        document.getElementById("endTime").innerHTML += h;
};
```

Where I am having the problem is using the if statement. Since this is the exact text that is being displayed I'm expecting it to append h to it. Instead it skips to the else statement and appends it to end time.

Comment: You didn't pass any argument to the document.getElementById inside the if guard. I feel like you want to do if (document.getElementById('startTime').innerHTML === "Start Time: ") { ...}

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (document.getElementById('startTime').innerHTML === "Start Time: ")
```

Comment: Thanks, should've caught that.

Answer (score 0):

What you're going for, is probably something like this :

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    return [
       ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2),
       ("0" + (date.getMinutes())).slice(-2),
       ("0" + (date.getSeconds())).slice(-2)
    ].join(':');
}

var startTime;
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var d = new Date();
    if (typeof startTime === "undefined") {
        startTime = d;
        document.getElementById("startTime").innerHTML = formatDate(d);
        document.getElementById("endTime").innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById("totalSeconds").innerHTML = '';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("endTime").innerHTML = formatDate(d);
        document.getElementById("totalSeconds").innerHTML = (d - startTime) / 1000;
        startTime = undefined;
    }
});
```

```html
<h2>Start Time: <span id="startTime"></span></h2>
<h2>End Time: <span id="endTime"></span></h2>
<h2>Total Seconds: <span id="totalSeconds"></span></h2>
<button class="button button1" id="myBtn">clock in</button>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1mgz7gwj/2/))

---

#### Note

For my demo, I calculated the number of seconds between start and end time instead of the number of hours, because that makes more sense in the context of the demo.

If you want the total number instead of the total number of seconds, just divide the number of seconds by 3600.